# How do i create a Godzilla style roar and some giant sounding footsteps?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, effects, film-sound-design

I want to creat a massive roar for a sound scape i'm working on but i'm new to this so any tips would be greatly appreciated =) thanks in advance

Comment: What equipment do you have? I'd start by recording my own voice and distorting it.

Comment: Yup, recording my voice tonight. Gonna have a go at slowing down some Animal samples i've got.

Comment: I have ableton, protools, a fair few plug-ins and a mic.

Comment: Honestly the best thing you can do is experiment; omnesilere has suggested a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gorillas walruses & time stretch. Godzilla was largely a leather glove on a detuned bass string, if I remember correctly. Depends on what's roaring though